# Mounting a raw hard drive read-only in Virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, mount, vmdk

Is it possible to give a VirtualBox VM read-only access to a physical HDD? I've read up on the `createrawvmdk` documentation, but it seems that it can only give it full read-write access.

Comment: Host and guest operating systems?

Comment: Guest is Windows 7. Host is also Windows 7, or if necessary, any Linux live DVD I can boot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [StarWind VSAN](https://www.starwindsoftware.com/starwind-virtual-san-free) for that purpose. While creating a Device check physical disk and configure ISCSI Read-Only Disk bridge. 
[image]
[image]